# Time update of Google Analytics dataset on BigQuery

Tags: time, google-analytics, google-bigquery

Our website has set data transfer from Google Analytics to BigQuery daily. However, daily dataset in BQ is usually available around 7:30am to 10:30am (GMT+1). Is there any way to make the update sooner (early in the morning) ?

Our website is located in Netherlands but Google Analytic dataset in BigQuery is stored in US.

Comment: Unfortunately I believe the answer in no.

Answer (score 1):

I would agree with OWOX BI.
The intraday updates from one account to another are different on no set schedule. At the end of the three intraday update, this data is then loaded into the daily table for that day. In this case, you can use an on-demand SQL query using cloud functions to pick up the log message when the daily table load is complete (if this is what you are looking for).

For more information:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can't control the time when BQ tables will be created     Actually, you can't control the time when BQ tables will be created